# Sharing completed scripts in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple script in ruby and want to share it with someone. What would be the easiest way to send it to them so they can run it and check it out? I would prefer to send it to them already running if that's possible (as in not sending them the whole script but having them open a file and seeing what the script does).

Comment: Just email them the `.rb` file ...? Or use some instant message, dropbox, etc... I'm not sure that I understand where you're confused? It's like any other file

Comment: This makes no sense. You want to send them a *running* script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is you can't.

ruby is  programming language - they have to run it on their machine n order to get the results of it running. That means they have to download a copy onto their machine and deliberately run it on their machine.

So - email it to them and tell them to run "ruby <yourfilemame.rb>"

If you just want to send them the results... then just send them a file containing the results.

Comment: The results require user input. I'm assuming then the answer would be to just send it to them and have them run it like you said, correct?

Comment: yep - it's the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script by yourself in terminal on your own computer and record what happening using 'showterm' gem. Then, you just share the [link.](http://showterm.io/7b5f8d42ba021511e627e)
More info here. http://showterm.io/